# direct parameters VS. saved values in variables

Tags: php, mysql, function

Should this function:

```
function get_article_info(){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $data = array();
        $q = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = $id";
        $qry = mysql_query($q);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

be the same as this one:

```
function get_article_info2(){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $data = array();
        $q = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = $id"));

        while($row = $q){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

If I try to use get_article_info2 I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes)
```

Can any tell me why it's not working ?
Thx ;)

Comment: You really shouldn't be usung `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated and are no longer supported, look into **PDO** or **mysqli** instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $q = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = $id"));

    while($row = $q){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
```

There is no end to this loop, because you assign a value to $q once before, and it never changes. So the same row is appended to $data over and over again, and finally your script runs out of memory.

You have to call the fetch function for every record separately (as in the first code).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should *always* escape or sanitize your SQL parameters:

```
$sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = %d', (int)$_GET['id']);
$res = mysql_query($sql);
```

Second, you should perform `mysql_fetch_assoc()` *inside* the loop; otherwise it will cause an endless loop:

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req)) !== false) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

That said, you should stop using the old `mysql_*` functions; use PDO or mysqli instead and harness the power of prepared statements.

Comment: Jack Y U NO SQL INJECTION warning ?

Comment: @Null didn't I mention the parameters should be escaped or sanitised? Did I miss something?

Comment: yes you did very well ,but i think its better to tell why to escape or sanitize  parameter's .. :-) yes and +1

Comment: @Null I reckoned the escape-or-die-horrible-death dogma could work too :)

Comment: thx for the answers guys. my school are learning os the old mysql way. thats why i use it (and 500 other students). ;)

Comment: @Mads that's fair enough, but SQL injection attacks are very real so feel free to let your teachers know about it :)